# SQL Server auto spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, spaces, sqldatatypes

I create a table in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio with a datatype `nchar(100)` in it.

If I put some data in it, then it automatically adds spaces at the end of my word I guess to fit the 100..

How can I edit this so it doesn't add spaces?

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NCHAR` and `CHAR` are *fixed* size types - that means that if the data inserted is not large enough, spaces will be inserted.

You need to change the type of the fields to `NVARCHAR` for variable length data.

See [nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx#) on MSDN for details.